# <f:ajax execute="newDate" listener="myBean.getResultByNewDate()"> return error message 'Server sent empty response'

Tags: jsf

Following is my JSF code

```
<h:input type="newDate">

<h:commandLink>
<f:ajax execute="newDate" listener="myBean.getResultByNewDate()">
</h:commandLink>
```

In the backing bean, the newDate field is defined as Date and method getResultByNewDate() is also defined. But on click of the command link, I get a error message: "Server sent empty response".

I need to use the newDate's value in the getResultByNewDate(). Any suggestions to fix this issue. Is the syntax correct?

Comment: There are multiple issues in the code. Like listener = "#{myBean.getResultByNewDate()}". And execute should have the id of the xhtml element which you want o execute as the ajax, not the backing bean binding. And as far as I can recall it should be inputText and type should be replaced with value="#{myBean.newDate}"

Comment: Hi, like @GuarevJeswani said, there are many basic things wrong in your code. Please take a step back and start reading some good tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSF code has multiple issues:

1) `input` should be replaced with `inputText`.
2) `type` also has no use here.
3) `listener` should use proper binding.
4) `execute` should use the `id` of the xhtml component which need to be executed on ajax.

Code should be like:

```
<h:inputText value="#{myBean.newDate}" id="dateInput">

<h:commandLink>
<f:ajax execute="dateInput" listener="#{myBean.getResultByNewDate()}">
</h:commandLink>
```

Extra point to note, if you would have used `commandButton` on place of `commandLink`, you should declare the `type="button"`, otherwise you will face issue with ajax. Because ajax work with type `button` and `commandButton` is of type `submit` by default and `commadLink` is of type `button` by default.

Comment: Thanks for correcting the syntax. With the above corrected code, I get a error message "Server sent empty response". Can <f:ajax>  have a execute field and a listener as well.

Comment: Yes it can have both together. Where you are getting message?

Comment: On click of the command link, there is a popup with the error message.

Comment: looks like error is originating from some other flow.